# Conditioning on defined types in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I have defined the following types in Racket:

```
(define-type vname (Pairof String Integer))

(define-type term (U vname (Listof (Pairof String term))))

(define-type subst (Listof (Pairof vname term)))
```

How would I define a procedure `(lift s t)` with signature `(-> subst term term)` that is conditioned on whether `t` is of type `vname` or `(Listof (Pairof String term))`? Is there a an easy way to test the actual type of a union type? If I instead had `(define-type term (U String Integer))`, I could use `string?` to test whether `t` is a string; how would I extend this to my situation?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues in Typed Racket and I found it simpler to define structs for all of my nontrivial types. Then you can distinguish between types using the struct predicates, eg.

```
(struct vname (name val))
(vname? (struct "foo" 5))
```

Comment: But how would I define `term` using a struct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your problem. But it looks like you can define a `(struct foo (str term)`, and then `(define-type term (U vname (Listof foo))`. You could even define a struct to wrap the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

A union is not a discriminated union, so there isn't automatically a way to do this. However, in this particular case you can distinguish between the two because a `vname` will always be a pair with an `Integer` in the `cdr` position, whereas a value of type `(Listof (Pairof String term))` will be either `'()` or else will be a pair with a (possibly empty) list in the `cdr` position. So the predicate `vname?` could be defined as:

```
(define (vname? x)
  (and (pair? x) (exact-integer? (cdr x))))
```